# Using find_or_create_by to update table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv

I have a table that I am trying to update after I have made changes to the url column. Currently, the data is seeded into the databse when I run `rake db:seed`, but if I make changes to the csv, in this case to the url, I want to update the table to reflect that change. Currently, the table will not update that value.

```
require 'csv'

datafile = Rails.root + 'db/data.csv'

CSV.foreach(datafile, headers: true) do |row|

  Data.find_or_create_by({address: row[0]}) do |hr|
    hr.address = row[0]
    hr.city =  row[1]
    hr.state =  row[2]
    hr.zip =  row[3]
    hr.name =  row[4]
    hr.url = row[5]
  end

end

CSV.foreach(datafile, headers: true) do |row|

  Data.find_or_create_by({url: row[5]}) do |hr|
    hr.url = row[5]
  end

end
```

I tried doing the find_or_create_by on just the url (row[5]), but those changes are not being reflected. How can I make this seed file update any changes or new entries in the CSV in the postgreSQL database?

Comment: `find_or_create` does not update the record if it already exists. You hate to explicitly call a `save` or `update_attributes` method if you want to update an existing record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CSV.foreach(datafile, headers: true) do |row|
  Data.find_or_create_by({url: row[5]}) do |hr|
    hr.url = row[5]

    # call the save method, to saved the change
    hr.save 
  end
end
```